# Stripe Connect Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

Looked all over, tried capturing the code via swift but still need a function to fire off the code to get an Express account to connect.

Won't waste your time with the code attempts, so looking for Firebase Functions that will setup a Stripe Connect endpoint for redirection and send back the code to finalise the process.

Anyone care to help?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: [Here is a related video](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/stripe-recurring-subscription-payments-with-angular-and-firebase-cloud-functions/)

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe?

Comment: James, thx and that is on the right track. Frank, those functions don't apply at all bc they're for creating charges etc. Stripe Connect is a different part. Thx for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

1. Open a browser or web view from your App. Let the user work through the form to sign up for a Stripe account.
2. Use Firebase's ability to [call functions via HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), to define an endpoint that you can set as your [Connect redirect_uri](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#redirected). Let's say `https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/connect_redirect`
3. In your Firebase function, you will grab the `code` parameter that's included in the query string (`request.query.code`), then [to complete the connection process](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#token-request), use a [HTTP client](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) to POST the appropriate data to `https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token`
4. In the `return` of your Firebase function, either supply a message encouraging the user to close their browser, OR create a [redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect), directing the user back to your app (using something like a [custom url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) as the redirect destination)

Comment: Followed your steps, but my request doesn't seem to go out.  Would you mind taking a look @ this function and lmk if I missing something?  Thx to you, think I'm almost done with this part of the project.

Comment: Ben, would you be able to provide us future readers with the function that seemed to have worked? MANY THANKS- Guy from the Future

Comment: Yes ended up making some custom APIs for these functionality.  Unfortunately the API is custom tailored for the specific situation and I don't think any of its code would be valuable for me to share here.